# How to refresh another grid

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, aspxgridview

I have 2 tab pages and 2 grid in my Page. I have a custom button on my first grid. When I click it want to databind the second grid and go to second tab page. The problem is when I use ClientSideEvent click I can't use server side click method. I want to use both them. I added e.processOnServer = true for it. But it doesn't work. Where is my fault? 
Here is my code;

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid1" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="grid1" EnableRowsCache="False" KeyFieldName="Id" Width="100%" OnCustomButtonCallback="grid1_DetailButton" >
  <ClientSideEvents CustomButtonClick="function(s, e) {
    if(e.buttonID == 'Detail'){
     ASPxPageControl1.SetActiveTabIndex(1); 
     e.processOnServer = true; 
    }
  }" />
  <Columns>
    <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="4" ButtonType="Button">
      <CustomButtons>
        <dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton ID="Detail">
          <Styles Native="true"></Styles>
        </dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton>
      </CustomButtons>
    </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
  </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

My code in cs

```
protected void grid1_DetailButton(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomButtonCallbackEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ButtonID == "Detail") {
        grid2.DataSource = WebService.Get_Customers();
        grid2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try grid.refresh() from clientsideevent when click custom button?